# Reset iPython terminal in sphinx

Tags: python, ipython, python-sphinx

I'm using iPython's sphinx extension to write a documentation. From what I've realized, every call to ipython adds to the previous call. So if I have a file with

```
.. ipython:: python

   a=5

Some text

.. ipython:: python
   print(a)
```

It will work as it should, and the last code block will print 5.

However, the behavior when I have code blocks in different files is not clear to me. If I have, for example, in one file

```
.. ipython:: python

   import package
   package.option = 'other than default'
```

and in another file I have

```
.. ipython:: python

   import package
   print(package.option)
```

and if I compile the docs linking those two files sequentially sometimes the last print will print the package's default, and some other times it'll print `'other than default'`. Which is weird.

When I run `make clean` and then `make html` it appears to me that it always (from what I could tell) prints `"other than default"`. So the default behavior seems to be that one (additive).

I some questions.

- Is default behavior really additive when code blocks are in different files?
- If so, why is it that sometimes that doesn't happen with me?
- Most importantly: Is there a command I can run that "resets" the iPython terminal? I want to make that my iPython callings start from scratch at every new file.

My sphinx version is 1.4.5 and my iPython version is 2.4.1.

Comment: When you run `make html`, it only rebuilds the files that have changes in them. This means that if your `'other than default`' file has no changes, the value will be obtained from the default import.

Comment: There may be a way to edit your makefile to make the two source files dependent on each other.

Comment: @MadPhysicist that explains why sometimes it works when I don't clean first. As far and changing the Makefile, I have no idea how to do that, but I'll check into it. So far I've tried to put `reset` in an iPython block call, but that doesn't work (I think) because iPython waits for my confirmation to reset.